# Can't execute async method in Background with workmanager

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, background-process

In my app, I need to execute some tasks in the background (while app is not running in foreground). I'm able to execute some methods in the background but, I need to execute an async method in the background which I can't.

Here is a part of my code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));

  Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
  Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask("1", "simplePeriodicTask",
      existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.replace,
      frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
      initialDelay:
          Duration(seconds: 5),
      constraints: Constraints(
        networkType: NetworkType.connected,
      ));
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) {
    _HomeState().manager();//This is not Working
    print('Background Services are Working!');//This is Working
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    login();
    super.initState();
  }

  void manager() async {
    if (account == null) {
      await login();
      await managerLocal();
      managerDrive();
    } else {
      await managerLocal();
      managerDrive();
    }
  }

  .......
  .......

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "don't work" and why you don't await your async method?

Comment: Don't work means it wasn't executed.

Comment: You start it and then instead of waiting for it, immediately tell your caller you are done. I would not expect it to be executed completely under such conditions.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: @nvoigt any solution. I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *wait* for your method to actually finish:

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    await _HomeState().manager();
    print('Background Services are Working!');//This is Working
    return true;
  });
}
```

Your `manager` method should probably return a `Future<void>`, since it is `async`.

If you are unsure how to work with `Future` data, feel free to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it/63017281#63017281).

Comment: I have used this same technique but the callback is not waiting for the await method and instead it just pass it to end the method execution, any idea about that?

Comment: Not really, sorry, I don't know your code. You should ask a new question about your specific code and problem.